# Get only one connected user at the same moment (with different phpsessid)

Tags: php, symfony, session

I want in symfony to get only one user connected at the same time, I really don't know how to do that.

**Examples:**

- Connecting with mozilla, I get my `PHPSESSID=a9oe3oc1mjsdh4dmtbcp1ljkq4 for user 'Plop'`
- Connecting with google chrome, I get my `PHPSESSID=di14cim632ui2rda3471sbr8n0 for same user 'Plop'`

I want invalidate mozilla's session to get only chrome session working, how can I do that?

Comment: This question is unclear, in your example only *Plop* is connected, so there is only one user connected at the same time, even if it's with 2 sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever user get logined keep his detail like PHPSESSID, Browser detail, IP Address and etc in db and also in hidden fields or in coockie or in session .

Now when user login again on different browser or on different PC update these details in DB.

Now to logout user from first session you need to keep matching these details with database and if these are different logout him.

To keep checking continuously you can use ajax. 
Means keep comparing the session/cookie/hidden field details with DB.

Comment: Why would you need to continuously keep checking? Just check on page load.

Comment: Since the cookie is only available for the connected user, how do you check that he/she is not the only one connected user? You can't check other users' cookies.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ like as facebook, whatsappweb do. open facebook in two different tabs and then logout from one tab and check second one. You dont need to refresh the seond tab, fb will automatically give you popup that please login.

Comment: @A.L My mean to say, store any info like sessionid  or any unique id in cookie instead of storing them in hidden fields and on page load get cookie and compare it with DB.

Comment: @ajaykumartak cookie data can be edited by the client, so probably not the best way to store sensitive data.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ ya i m agree with you, so if we are using cookie we can use a random unique id for our session and will store the same id in DB and on behalf of it we can compare. I just suggest him the way to do. Obviously security should be his major concern while implementing things.